# How to use string aggregation on concatenated result subquery in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, concatenation

I am trying to use string aggregation on the results of a subquery that contains concatenated results. I would like to create a long text string containing the qualified name "schema.table" for a DB schema I have in Postgres. Do you know how to achieve it? Below is the code I have come up with (not working), it says 
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.

```
SELECT string_agg(
    (SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) table_schema_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'name_of_schema'), ' ')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'name_of_schema'
```

what I have now is:

```
| table_schema_name | 

name_of_schema.table1
name_of_schema.table2
name_of_schema.table3
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
|                          agrreagated field                     |

name_of_schema.table1 name_of_schema.table2 name_of_schema.table3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do the task you're asking for:

```
SELECT string_agg(CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name), ' ')
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
```

Comment: Yes this one did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use the query as table expression in your outer select:

```
SELECT string_agg(s.table_schema_name, ' ') FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) AS table_schema_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
) s
```

or simply avoid the sub-select:

```
SELECT string_agg(CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name), ' ')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'public';
```